# Create docx with older msword8.h using Office 2010

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, ole, office-automation

When using Office Automation with MFC we have an old application written in Visual C++ that uses the headers from msword8.h of Word97, were are changing our systems to use Office 2010 i would like to know if without updating the msword8 files could i change the fileformat parameter while saving  to save in .docx or do i need to update to new headers?

Sorry if i am not expressing myself right but i don't know a lot C++ and much less Windows programming. If any aclaration is needed be sure to ask.

Bonus question:
The way the SaveAs method is used is like: doc.SaveAs(filename, VT_BSTR)
I cant find where VT_BSTR was declared or how can i modify it, if some one could point me to the right direction it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using  office 97  you can't change file format. To save in word97 type you can use the following code.

```
COleVariant vOpt((long)DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND,VT_ERROR),vTrue((short)TRUE), vFalse((short)FALSE);
cstring filename;//send file path.
oDoc.SaveAs(filename,vOpt,vOpt,vOpt,vOpt,vOpt,vOpt,vOpt,vOpt,vOpt,vOpt,vOpt,vOpt,vOpt,vOpt,vOpt);
```

It's not possible to change `VT_BSTR`, is a pre defined enum which means: `VT_BSTR [V][T][P][S]`

OLE Automation string it's declared in wtypes.h.